# STM stopwatch for UART

Tags: stm32, uart

For STM i am implementing a stopwatch, that starts right after the message is sent with UART and then stops when an answer is received with UART . I wanto to stop it exactly at the time the start bit is received or as close to that as possible. Any ideas?

currently i stop right after first byte is received

Comment: The receiver of the UART can only generate an interrupt after the stop bit has been processed. There's no event, not even an error condition, that is generated when the "*start bit is received or as close to that as possible*". Note however that the time duration of the UART frame is known and constant. But interrupt latency is the real problem.

Comment: You can configure a timer in input capture mode connected to the RX pin (in addition to the UART). The timer then captures its counter value when the pin go low, i.e. when the start bit starts.

Comment: BTW: Are you using UART over USB? If so, the precision will be heavily affected by the USB protocol and its complex (and chip dependent) scheduling.